# Distribution for the "total spend" metric

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I am working on a hypothesis test dataset that has "total spend" as the outcome metric. When I look at the distribution for this metric (dataset is at the user level and randomization is user level), I see about 30% of users in control and test groups have 0 orders and 0 spend. This makes the distribution non normal. What is a way to handle this?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated? Handle for what? What technique are you using that assumes a Gaussian distribution?